# How to find all records(form list) from given time range in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have to have an input function which allowes me to find specyfic records (form list created before) in time range like f.ex : album range? Input-> between 3 - 5 hours, -> two album was found in ouput

Comment: What code have you written to do that and what issues are you facing with it?

Answer (score 0):

This is an code that represent your question, feel free to ask question about it:

```
class Album:
    release_time: int

    def __init__(self, release_time):
        self.release_time = release_time

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Album({self.release_time})"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    album_list = [Album(i) for i in range(10)]
    user_input_min, user_input_max = (int(input('min?')), int(input('max?')))
    if user_input_min > user_input_max:
        print("error")
    else:
        album_nbr = 0
        result_list = list()
        for album in album_list:
            if user_input_min <= album.release_time <= user_input_max:
                album_nbr += 1
                result_list.append(album)
        print(album_list)
        print(f'{album_nbr} was found')
        print(result_list)
```

Output:

```
min?3
max?8
[Album(0), Album(1), Album(2), Album(3), Album(4), Album(5), Album(6), Album(7), Album(8), Album(9)]
6 was found
[Album(3), Album(4), Album(5), Album(6), Album(7), Album(8)]
```

Comment: Hello Dorian! We finally solved it out in our way, but thanks for your code ... It works Great

Comment: I'm glad to hear that @KamilZalewski. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.